# resetting positional parameters and account for spaces in arguments

Tags: shell

To reset positional parameters such as `$1 $2 $3 $4`, one can run commands similar to what's shown below:

```
var1=first
var2=second
var3=third

set -- $var1 $var2 $var3

echo $var1
first
echo $var2
second
echo $var3
third
```

This is all fine and dandy.  But suppose the arguments have spaces in them:

```
var1=first
var2="second 2 whatever"
var3=third
var4="now is good"
```

Is there a portable way to ensure after running `set -- $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4` the quotes in var2 and var4 are preserved?

That way, when i run a `echo $var2` i get `second 2 whatever` instead of `"second`

Comment: You mean `echo "$2"`, right? In that case, you want `set -- "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"`. In general, unquoted expansion is *always* buggy, and should never be done -- see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Nothing about this is specific to `set --`; the rules in play apply to all expansions except in very narrow and specific contexts like `[[ ]]`, or the right-hand side of a simple assignment.

Comment: ...if you pasted your code into http://shellcheck.net/ (with the multi-word constants), btw, it would link you to [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086).